# Render two model json in rails for angular front end

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, json

Very new to angular on rails. Basic app idea is to let anyone view venues. Click on venues. Make comments. At the moment I have a single model: venue. Hard-coded data. Full crud. Renders as JSON.
  Basically I want nested resources. Comments are not useful except in the context of the venue they belong to. I'm trying to find information about how I should create associations in rails api. Like does the venue have many comments such that active record knows about it? Or do I just pass comments as a hash attribute to the single venue model, and if so, how?

Comment: Use ActiveSerializers..  You can override attributes data structures in any format and can easily use nested attributes

Comment: Thanks. ActiveSerializers worked well!

Comment: Can you please upvote for the below answer i had suggested? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use ActiveModelSerializers.  You can override attributes data structures in any format and can easily use nested resources.https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers

Comment: @mfournier91 I understand my answer helped you,  
Can you please upvote for the above answer i had suggested? thanks!